# Conjugating verb for "to write LaTeX"

Tags: pronunciation

The verb "to LaTeX a paper" seems fairly commonplace. How does one conjugate this verb? I.e. would I say "John LaTeX's his work", "John LaTeXes his work", "John LaTeXs his work", or something else? Would this vary depending on how one chooses to pronounce "LaTeX", similar to "a historian"/"an historian"? (I pronounce it "lah-tech".)

Comment: This is off-topic as far as I can tell. But the first is definitely wrong unless you are talking about the work of somebody called John LaTeX. However, I don't think there is an answer. LaTeX cannot be *correctly* used as a verb given the current state of the language. That is, I don't think it would be appropriate to use 'to LaTeX a paper' in a formal context, even though people may say it informally. There just is not relevant standard of correctness governing its use as a verb. And it is very odd to pronounce 'historian' 'lah-tech'.

Comment: @cfr I am reminded of the English prof lecturing the students on the use of the `negative.'  "While it is not grammatically proper to employ a double negative to imply an emphatic negative, it is sometimes done nonetheless.  In no case, however, can a double positive be construed to mean the negative."  The student in the first row ponders this for a few seconds and mutters, "yeah, right."

Comment: LaTeXo, LaTeXare, LaTeXavi, LaTeXatum...

Comment: These are uses I consider idiomatic, as a native US English speaker and an academic in the humanities: I write my papers in LaTeX, or I use LaTeX to produce my documents. I wish my students would use LaTeX. They would benefit from writing their theses in LaTeX. I tried to compile a complicated LaTeX document but I realized my LaTeX was rusty.

Comment: In those examples, LaTeX is used as the name of a language ("in LaTeX" vs. "in Latin", same with "my LaTeX"); as the name of a system, program or tool ("in LaTeX" vs. "in MS Word" or "using LaTeX" vs. "using a hammer"); or the language used as adjective ("LaTeX document"). I can't think of an acceptable way to use it as a verb.

Comment: Interesting, I feel like everyone at my school uses it as a verb more commonly than any other form. It's worth knowing, then, I guess, that this might sound strange elsewhere!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The version I've heard involves a philosopher and 'yeah, yeah`.